# Isabelle/HOL foundations

Tags: isabelle

I have seen a lot of documentation about Isabelle's syntax and proof strategies. However, little have I found about its foundations. I have a few questions that I would be very grateful if someone could take the time to answer:

1. Why doesn't Isabelle/HOL admit functions that do not terminate? Many other languages such as Haskell do admit non-terminating functions.
2. What symbols are part of Isabelle's meta-language? I read that there are symbols in the meta-language for Universal Quantification (`/\`) and for implication (`==>`). However, these symbols have their counterpart in the object-level language (∀ and `-->`). I understand that `-->` is an object-level function of type `bool => bool => bool`. However, how are ∀ and ∃ defined? Are they object-level Boolean functions? If so, they are not computable (considering infinite domains). I noticed that I am able to write Boolean functions in therms of ∀ and ∃, but they are not computable. So what are ∀ and ∃? Are they part of the object-level? If so, how are they defined?
3. Are Isabelle theorems just Boolean expressions? Then Booleans are part of the meta-language?
4. As far as I know, Isabelle is a strict programming language. How can I use infinite objects? Let's say, infinite lists. Is it possible in Isabelle/HOL?

Sorry if these questions are very basic. I do not seem to find a good tutorial on Isabelle's meta-theory. I would love if someone could recommend me a good tutorial on these topics.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like a bunch of different questions. You should ask them one at a time.

Comment: for the first - if you want a proof assistant then you cannot have that ;) - see types <-> theorems and programs <-> proofs ...

Comment: see [propositions as types](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/propositions-as-types/propositions-as-types.pdf) "Untyped lambda calculus or typed lambda calculus with a construct
for general recursion (sometimes called a fixpoint operator)
permits the definition of any effectively computable function, but
have a Halting Problem that is unsolvable."

Comment: @Carsten True, yet Isabelle does not allow empty types -- one has that `undefined` is a valid Isabelle term inhabiting any type. So the standard type-theoretic argument "if we had full recursion we would be able to inhabit everything, hence prove everything" does not suffice. I know little about Isabelle, but coming from type theory it looks quite distant in some parts.

Comment: @chi I am afraid I cannot say anything about Isabella at all - but if what you write is true then yes you are right - although I guess that this is for *shortcuts* (cough) in the proofs ;) (it's not uncommon)

Comment: @Carsten Isabelle uses `sorry` for "cheating", as `Admitted` is used in Coq. AFAIK, `undefined` alone does not lead to inconsistencies in Isabelle, since all types must be inhabited anyway. I'm quite uncertain about the exact relationship Isabelle<->type theory, but it looks as if propositions are not types in Isabelle. I hope some Isabelle expert can clarify some points.

Comment: ok thanks - I'm far from being an expert (or even an student) in this // but I have to say I like `sorry` ;)

Comment: @chi That is something that I am having trouble understanding too. As far as I know propositions in Isabelle are just boolean expressions (not types!). You can have a theorem that states "Exists x such that is_prime x". You don't need to say "Exists x such that is_prime x = True". So it seems like theorems are just boolean formulas. Does this generate any inconsistence? Because it seems like I am talking about the object language (e.g booleans) using the object language. It is quite confusing. Theorems are normally expressed in terms of a meta-language.

Comment: @MartinCopes Reading `HOL.thy` in the Isabelle sources provides some definitions of some basic symbols. E.g. `True` is defined as an equality between the identity function and itself.

Comment: Isabelle/HOL is not a type theory. There are the three separate entities of types, terms, and theorems. The distinction between meta language (better: logical framework) and object language is for technical reasons: Isabelle allows the implementation of various different logics on top of the same reasoning kernel (HOL, ZF, HOL+LCF, CTT, FO, ...). In HOL, the statement of a theorem is indeed just a boolean expression. This does not lead to inconsistencies as theorems are separate entities, not just terms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. You can define non-terminating (i.e. partial) functions in Isabelle (cf. [Function package manual (section 8)](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/functions.pdf)). However, partial functions are more difficult to reason about, because whenever you want to use its definition equations (the `psimps` rules, which replace the `simps` rules of a normal function), you have to show that the function terminates on that particular input first.

In general, things like non-definedness and non-termination are always problematic in a logic – consider, for instance, the function ‘definition’ `f x = f x + 1`. If we were to take this as an equation on ℤ (integers), we could subtract `f x` from both sides and get `0 = 1`. In Haskell, this problem is ‘solved’ by saying that this is not an equation on ℤ, but rather on ℤ ∪ {⊥} (the integers plus bottom) and the non-terminating function `f` evaluates to ⊥, and ‘⊥ + 1 = ⊥’, so everything works out fine.

However, if every single expression in your logic could potentially evaluate to ⊥ instead of a ‘proper‘ value, reasoning in this logic will become very tedious. This is why Isabelle/HOL chooses to restrict itself to total functions; things like partiality have to be emulated with things like `undefined` (which is an arbitrary value that you know nothing about) or option types.

2. I'm not an expert on Isabelle/Pure (the meta logic), but the most important symbols are definitely

- `⋀` (the universal meta quantifier)
- `⟹` (meta implication)
- `≡` (meta equality)
- `&&&` (meta conjunction, defined in terms of `⟹`)
- `Pure.term`, `Pure.prop`, `Pure.type`, `Pure.dummy_pattern`, `Pure.sort_constraint`, which fulfil certain internal functions that I don't know much about.

You can find some information on this in the [Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2015/doc/isar-ref.pdf) in section 2.1, and probably more elsewhere in the manual.

Everything else (that includes ∀ and ∃, which indeed operate on boolean expressions) is defined in the object logic (HOL, usually). You can find the definitions, of rather the axiomatisations, in `~~/src/HOL/HOL.thy` (where `~~` denotes the Isabelle root directory):

```
All_def:      "All P     ≡ (P = (λx. True))"
Ex_def:       "Ex P      ≡ ∀Q. (∀x. P x ⟶ Q) ⟶ Q"
```

Also note that many, if not most Isabelle functions are typically not computable. Isabelle is **not** a programming language, although it does have a code generator that allows exporting Isabelle functions as code to programming languages as long as you can give code equations for all the functions involved.

3)
Isabelle theorems are a complex datatype (cf. `~~/src/Pure/thm.ML`) containing a lot of information, but the most important part, of course, is the *proposition*. A proposition is something from Isabelle/Pure, which in fact only has propositions and functions. (and `itself` and `dummy`, but you can ignore those).

Propositions are *not* booleans – in fact, there isn't even a way to state that a proposition does not hold in Isabelle/Pure.

HOL then defines (or rather axiomatises) booleans and also axiomatises a coercion from booleans to propositions: `Trueprop :: bool ⇒ prop`

4. Isabelle is **not** a programming language, and apart from that, totality does not mean you have to restrict yourself to finite structures. Even in a total programming language, you can have infinite lists. (cf. Idris's `codata`)

Isabelle is a theorem prover, and logically, infinite objects can be treated by axiomatising them and then reasoning about them using the axioms and rules that you have.

For instance, HOL assumes the existence of an infinite type and defines the natural numbers on that. That already gives you access to functions `nat ⇒ 'a`, which are essentially infinite lists.

You can also define infinite lists and other infinite data structures as codatatypes with the [(co-)datatype package](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle/doc/datatypes.pdf), which is based on bounded natural functors.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add some points to two of your questions.

> 1) Why doesn't Isabelle/HOL admit functions that do not terminate? Many other languages such as Haskell do admit non-terminating functions.

In short: Isabelle/HOL does not require *termination*, but *totality* (i.e., there is a specific result for each input to the function) of functions. Totality does not mean that a function is actually terminating when transcribed to a (functional) programming language or even that it is computable at all.

Therefore, talking about *termination* is somewhat misleading, even though it is encouraged by the fact that Isabelle/HOL's function package uses the keyword `termination` for proving some property `P` about which I will have to say a little more below.

On the one hand the term "termination" might sound more intuitive to a wider audience. On the other hand, a more precise description of `P` would be *well-foundedness of the function's call graph*.

Don't get me wrong, `termination` is not really a bad name for the property `P`, it is even justified by the fact that many techniques that are implemented in the function package are very close to *termination techniques* from term rewriting or functional programming (like the size-change principle, dependency pairs, lexicographic orders, etc.).

I'm just saying that it can be misleading. The answer to why that is the case also touches on question 4 of the OP.

> 4) As far as I know Isabelle is a strict programming language. How can I use infinite objects? Let's say, infinite lists. Is it possible in Isabelle/HOL?

*Isabelle/HOL* is **not** a programming language and it specifically **does not** have any evaluation strategy (we could alternatively say: *it has any evaluation strategy you like*).

And here is why the word *termination* is misleading (drum roll): if there is no evaluation strategy and we have termination of a function `f`, people might expect `f` to terminate *independent of the used strategy*. But this is not the case. A `termination` proof of a `function` rather ensures that `f` is well-defined. Even if `f` is computable a proof of `P` merely ensures that *there is an evaluation strategy* for which `f` terminates.

(As an aside: what I call "strategy" here, is typically influenced by so called *cong*-rules (i.e., congruence rules) in Isabelle/HOL.)

As an example, it is trivial to prove that the function (see Section 10.1 *Congruence rules and evaluation order* in the documentation of the function package):

```
fun f' :: "nat ⇒ bool"
where
  "f' n ⟷ f' (n - 1) ∨ n = 0"
```

terminates (in the sense defined by `termination`) after adding the cong-rule:

```
lemma [fundef_cong]:
  "Q = Q' ⟹ (¬ Q' ⟹ P = P') ⟹ (P ∨ Q) = (P' ∨ Q')"
by auto
```

Which essentially states that logical-or should be "evaluated" from right to left. However, if you write the same function e.g. in OCaml it causes a stack overflow ...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this answer is not really correct, check out Lars' comment below.

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment, so here is my go at an answer (please bear in mind I am no expert in Isabelle, but I also had similar questions once):

1) The idea is to prove statements about the defined functions. I am not sure how familiar you are with Computability Theory, but think about the Halting Problem and the fact most undeciability problems stem from it (such as Acceptance Problem). Imagine defining a function which you can't prove it terminates. How could you then still prove it returns the number 42 when given input "ABC" and it doesn't go in an infinite loop?

If instead you limit yourself to terminating functions, you can prove much more about them, essentially making a trade-off (or at least this is how I see it).

These ideas stem from Constructivism and Intuitionism and I recommend you check out Robert Harper's very interesting lecture series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SnefrwBIDc&list=PLGCr8P_YncjXRzdGq2SjKv5F2J8HUFeqN on Type Theory

You should check out especially the part about the **absence of the Law of Excluded middle**: http://youtu.be/3JHTb6b1to8?t=15m34s

2) See Manuel's answer.

3,4) Again see Manuel's answer keeping in mind Intuitionistic logic: "the fundamental entity is not the boolean, but rather the proof that something is true".

For me it took a long time to get adjusted to this way of thinking and I'm still not sure I understand it. I think the key though is to understand it is a more-or-less completely different way of thinking.

Comment: Restricting the logic of Isabelle/HOL has nothing to do with the halting problem or constructivism. HOL is not an intuitionistic logic! Rather, non-terminating functions easily make the logic inconsistent, allowing the user to prove false. Consider f defined by "f n = 1 + f n". By subtracting "f n" on both sides, we proved "0 = 1". There are ways around this (e.g., by adding a separate value for non-termination), but reason becomes more cumbersome. LCF or Isabelle's HOLCF are examples of logics allowing non-terminating functions.

Comment: @LarsNoschinski Oh ok that's very helpful then, thanks for the clarification!